# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid input to toASCII: ip_nbae7bac35.kodrive.xyz

Tags: android, okhttp, android-networking

Is there a workaround for this exception? looking at this [issue on github](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2606) it sounds like it might be an android bug, something about the hostname having an underscore character or something.

This is the stack trace:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid input to toASCII: ip_nbae7bac35.kodrive.xyz
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:219)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:318)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:282)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:167)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your issue is that you can not convert a string to ASCII using toASCII that contains an `_`. There is no way around this other than to get in touch with the owner of the domain and ask them to remove the `_`.  This is why you got an `IllegalArgumentException`, the string was "illegal".

Comment: Getting same as there is underscore in host name. Is there any workaround for the same. Url is working is postman request but why not in retrofit request

Comment: Underscores are allowed in URLs. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.3 Pretty sad that toASCII() doesn't handle it.

Comment: There's solution to the problem, you can check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78095509/1078641

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem will write a code that will accept all ssl certificates hopefully you won't deal with it for hours like me. When I saw the approved comment, I thought it was insoluble, but I solved it :)

Kotlin code:

```
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Response
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import java.io.IOException
import java.security.SecureRandom
import java.security.cert.CertificateException
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager

class ExampleClient {
    companion object{
        private fun httpClient(accessToken: String): OkHttpClient.Builder? {
            return try { // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
                val trustAllCerts =
                    arrayOf<TrustManager>(
                        object : X509TrustManager {
                            @Throws(CertificateException::class)
                            override fun checkClientTrusted(
                                chain: Array<X509Certificate>,
                                authType: String
                            ) {
                            }

                            @Throws(CertificateException::class)
                            override fun checkServerTrusted(
                                chain: Array<X509Certificate>,
                                authType: String
                            ) {
                            }

                            override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate> {
                                return arrayOf()
                            }
                        }
                    )
                // Install the all-trusting trust manager
                val sslContext =
                    SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
                sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, SecureRandom())
                // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
                val sslSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory
                val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                builder.addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
                    @Throws(IOException::class)
                    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                        val original = chain.request()
                        // Request customization: add request headers
                        val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Authorization", accessToken)
                        val request = requestBuilder.build()
                        return chain.proceed(request)
                    }
                })
                builder.sslSocketFactory(
                    sslSocketFactory,
                    (trustAllCerts[0] as X509TrustManager)
                )
                builder.hostnameVerifier(HostnameVerifier { hostname, session -> true })
                builder
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                throw RuntimeException(e)
            }
        }
        fun getClient(accessToken: String):Retrofit{
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://sub_domain.base-url.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient(accessToken)!!.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }
    }

}
```

Java Code:

```
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import com.pixplicity.easyprefs.library.Prefs;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class Client {
    public static String deviceid;
    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    public static String BASE_URL = "https://base_url.com/api/";
    public static OkHttpClient.Builder getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {

        try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                        }
                    }
            };

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request original = chain.request();

                    String token;
                    try {
                        token = Prefs.getString("token","Token not found");
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        token = LoginActivity.getToken();
                    }

                    // Request customization: add request headers
                    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                            .header("deviceid", deviceid).addHeader("Authorization","Bearer " + token);


                    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            });
            builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);
            builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            return builder;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }



    public static Retrofit getClient(String device_id){

        deviceid = device_id;
        MyLog.log("DEVICE ID : "+deviceid);
        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient().build())
                    .build();
            return retrofit;
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

Comment: But is that allowed on the Play Store? I thought trust managers that trusted all certs weren't allowed on the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the issue with a call to the server with _ (underscore) in subdomain you need to change SSLContext from Conscrypt to something else, for example [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html).

In order to do that you need first to add dependencies to your application level build.gradle

```
// Check the actual version at the BouncyCastle website
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15to18:1.77'
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.77'
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bctls-jdk15to18:1.77'
```

Then you need to override default SecurityProvider for the app. For that you can create a new class App which extends Application with the following code

```
import android.app.Application;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider;

import java.security.Security;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


        Security.removeProvider("BC");
    // Confirm that positioning this provider at the end works for your needs!

    Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider(), 1);
    Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 2);
    }
}
```

You need to add your App class to the AndroidManifest.xml application tag

```
<application
        ...
        android:name=".App"
    ...
```

After that changes OkHttpClient should be already use BouncyCastle and call to the subdomain must happen. However you probably will get error with unknown certificate `org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: certificate_unknown`.

You can check that answer in order to set the key https://stackoverflow.com/a/72235440

However for the development purposes you might want to skip that step, then you need to slightly adopt @Gorkem KARA answer and create your custom version of HttpClient with BouncyCastleJsseProvider

```
private static OkHttpClient.Builder getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {

    try {

        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {

            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {

            }

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                X509Certificate[] cArrr = new X509Certificate[0];
                return cArrr;
            }

        }};


        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2", BouncyCastleJsseProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);

        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        builder.sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory(), (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);

        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Trust Host");
                return true;
            }

        };
        builder.hostnameVerifier( hostnameVerifier);

        return builder;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

After that you can use your unsafeOkHttpClient version

```
Retrofit retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient().build())
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

/**
 * 忽略https证书验证
 */

public class SSLSocketClient {
    //获取这个SSLSocketFactory
    public static SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory() {
        try {
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, getTrustManager(), new SecureRandom());
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    //获取TrustManager
    private static TrustManager[] getTrustManager() {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[]{};
            }
        }};
        return trustAllCerts;
    }

    //获取HostnameVerifier
    public static HostnameVerifier getHostnameVerifier() {
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        return hostnameVerifier;
    }
}
```

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = ...
builder.sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketClient.getSSLSocketFactory())
       .hostnameVerifier(SSLSocketClient.getHostnameVerifier())
```

Comment: Can you add some more details to your answer? What does it do different to the accepted answer?

Comment: I didn't post this answer but basically it accepts all hostnames I think. I have no implemented this as I don't think Google allows this on the Play Store, at least I've heard that.

Comment: This is just an example. You should add your own certificate. If you add ssh support, there will be no `_ ` error. So there is no IllegalArgumentException